# What is the List<T> Class?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I cannot understand this piece of code:

```
 public class BookCategory
 {
     public string CategoryName { get; set; }
     public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
 }
 public class Book
 {
     public string Title
     {
         get;
         set;
     }
 }
```

What does it mean `List<Book>`, and does it inherit from class `Book` or not ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`List<Book>`*<sup>[[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)]</sup>* is a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) collection of `Book` objects. It doesn't inherit from `Book`. Rather, it *contains* zero or more `Book` objects in a *collection*.

Because the `List<T>` class is generic, it can be reused to provide list operations on a collection of any type of object. You can have `List<int>`, `List<string>`, `List<object>`, etc., but they all work from the same `List<T>` class, which is a great example of the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). In this example, `T` is called the type parameter and can be any .NET or user-defined type.

You can define you're own generic classes. Here's a trivial example of the syntax:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public T AnObject { get; set; }

    public Foo(T anObject)
    {
        AnObject = anObject;
    }
}
```

Some other very useful .NET generics are:

- `Stack<T>`*<sup>[[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)]</sup>*
- `Queue<T>`*<sup>[[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)]</sup>*
- `Nullable<T>`*<sup>[[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)]</sup>*
- `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`*<sup>[[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)]</sup>*
- and many more...

Generics are very useful and pervasive in .NET, so definitely familiarize yourself with this concept.

Answer (score 3):

`List<Book>` is a **list of books**.

- It's different than an `ArrayList`, since the list can only contain objects of type `Book` (or a subtype thereof).
- It's different than an array of books (`book[]`), since a List data structure is dynamically sized and optimized for adding and removing items.

The notation `List<Book>` means: class [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), using `Book` as the generic type parameter `T`. For an introduction to generics (what they are, what problems they solve), I recommend the following article on MSDN:

- [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564.aspx)

To answer your second question:  No, it does not inherit from `Book`. Think of it like a bookshelf: It can contain books, but it is not a book itself: The bookshelf does not have a title, nor does it have an author.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx), a way of taking the type of an object into account to make strongly typed assumptions for an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a Generic class and has been available since .NET 2.0

It contains a list of Book objects

Comment: There is no non-generic `List`.

Comment: @Adam: Back in 2002 we used ArrayList while we were waiting for Generics. ArrayList can be seen as non-generic list (although the name is slightly different)

Comment: @Fule: That was what I was getting at; the answer said that `List` was non-generic, and that `List<Book>` was generic, as if there were two different versions of the same type. While `ArrayList` is similar, it is a different type.

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic container class whose elements have to be Book instances. The key word is *generic* and every C# text book will cover this concept.

Answer (score 0):

in other terms

```
 List<Book> Books
```

will create a list of book objects named Books